Is there a standard term for averaging based on monotonic function?
Let consider function $f(x)$ of real argument, such that $f$ is monotonic on some interval $[a;b]$ and $f^{-1}$ is inverse function. Let $x_i\in[a;b]$ for $i=1,2,...,n$. Then $$\bar{x}=f^{-1}\left(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \right)$$ is kind of average for numbers $x_i$. It lies between minimal and maximal of these numbers and it increases with increase of any of these numbers.
Is there standard term for such average $\bar{x}$?
Note: for $f(x)=x$ value $\bar{x}$ is arithmetic mean, for $f(x)=x^2$ value $\bar{x}$ is quadratic mean, for $f(x)=\log x$ value $\bar{x}$ is geometric mean, for $f(x)=1/x$ value $\bar{x}$ is harmonic mean of numbers $x_i$

These are quasi-arithmetic means.
According to Wikipedia, they are also the "generalised $f$-mean" or "Kolmogorov-Nagumo-de Finetti mean" or just "Kolmogorov mean".
